# appended text using jQuery does not appear in proper format

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have following jQuery and HTML code

```js
var i = 2;
$('#addbtn').click(function() {
  i = i + 1;
  $('#options').append('<label for="' + i + '" class="black-text">' + i + '.</label><input id="' + i + '" type="text">');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="options" class="row">
  <label for="1" class="black-text">1.</label>
  <input id="1" type="text">
  <label for="2" class="black-text">2.</label>
  <input id="2" type="text">
</div>

<button id="addbtn" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light blue" style="font-size:20;" href="" onclick="return false;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
```

I want to append more options as I click on add button.
But I am unable to figure out what is wrong in this code. when I click on add button for the first time, the appended text appears at the right top corner of the page (unlike below the option 2) and as I keep clicking on the button the appended text eventually keeps moving towards left. Hope the problem is clear enough.
Thanks.

Comment: you can add <br> to append new line

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div tag

```js
var i = 2;
$('#addbtn').click(function() {
  i = i + 1;
  $('#options').append('<div><label for="' + i + '" class="black-text">' + i + '.</label><input id="' + i + '" type="text"></div>');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="options" class="row">
  <div><label for="1" class="black-text">1.</label>
  <input id="1" type="text"></div>
  <div><label for="2" class="black-text">2.</label>
  <input id="2" type="text"></div>
</div>

<button id="addbtn" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light blue" style="font-size:20;" href="" onclick="return false;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
```

Comment: That was helpful, didn't solve the problem completely though. I figured it out. Thanks anyway.

Comment: And how did you do that

Comment: As you suggested, I used div but the new appended text was still right aligned. So instead of using "append", I gave "id" to the div and used "insertAfter " and that worked perfectly for me.